# How to redefine a class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

If I have already defined a class A, how can I overwrite its definition and define a new class A?

Or, can I remove the definition of an existing class? So, I can define it again.

Comment: You really should post some code. There's not really any such thing as a "class" in JavaScript.

Comment: You can replace a constructor's prototype so that new instances inherit from that, or you can replace the methods on the current prototype so all instances get them. Your call.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I will manage some example code.

Answer (score 0):

javascript defenition of a class is so flexible that you can do what you are asking for, you just have to test

```
user = function() 
{ 
         this.login = "username"; 
         this.password="123"; 
}
var User1 = new user();
console.log(User1.login + " " + User1.password);
```

you can define another class with the same name, and this will break the first definition

```
user = function()
{
         this.name = "abc";
         this.age = 24;
}
var User2 = new user();
console.log(User2.name+ " " + User2.age);
```